# ASP.NET Core Capture HTTP Status Code 413 Payload Too Large / Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In Statup.cs -> Configure:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCodeError/{0}");
```

I was trying to capture this one:
**413 Payload Too Large**, Previously called "**Request Entity Too Large**"

I just cant seem to get any middleware to fire when a 413 is triggered, guess IIS looks after it?

Just want to know the best approach to handle this as don't really want to show the user the default iis error message.

I tried adding this in to the web.config, but then this stopped other status codes working e.g. 404:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="413" />
  <error statusCode="413" path="/StatusCodeError/413" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

Thank you

Comment: See following : https://andrewlock.net/re-execute-the-middleware-pipeline-with-the-statuscodepages-middleware-to-create-custom-error-pages/

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, I am already using UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute, works fine for other codes just wont work for the 413 code :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was happening why the status code error page was not displaying.

I added this to StatusCodeError.cshtml.cs

```
public void OnPost(int statusCode)
{
      OnGet(statusCode);
}
```

All my code was in the OnGet, but because the status code 413 was triggered on a POST nothing was happening.